# How do I delete my Ohloh profile?

Tags: account-management, profile

How do I go about deleting my Ohloh profile?

I have two Ohloh profiles. I want to delete one of them so that the profile that remains may use the email and username of the deleted profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really. Or at least it's not available unless you email support. And even then, who knows if they'll oblige.

If you need to swap around what username and email address is used, you can easily change them around.

You'll just need to set up a third username and email pair that will be used in the triage.

Say the account you want to delete/remove/no longer use is using huey@example.com and the one you want to keep is louie@example.com, change the profiles around like this:

1. louie@example.com → dewey@example.com

   Make sure you also change the username to something that doesn't exist. Now the louie@example.com email and its username is available to use since it's no longer tied to an account.
2. huey@example.com → louie@example.com

   Edit the username and the email of the account you want to keep with the email and username you want to use from the account you don't want to use anymore.